# Is it possible to use lightning-input as button-icon that display calendar above?

Tags: lightning-web-components, inputfield, date-picker

I have standard lwc lightning-input type="date" that looks like this:
[image]

And what I want to do is a button icon with the same functional, but without input field, just button with dropdown calendar.
Like this, but in square:

[image]

Do you have any ideas?

Updates: So, I found that calendar popup is actually lightning-calendar component, but there is no any documentation for it and i don't know how to get selected date to js controller from it

Answer (score 1):

what if you can reduce the size of input field will this work for you
For [Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/pdx0qvxSK1yyrPd3pGEw)